# Retrieving the font size of reactive native navigation title

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, font-size

I am a newbie...

I need to retrieve the font size used by the react native navigation title, so that i can use the same font size else where.  I see plenty documentation on how to set the font size.  I don't need to set it myself.  I just need to retrieve the font size, the default used.

I am using react native navigation 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to retrieve it, but you can inspect the view and figure it out, or also you can check the source code (god bless open source!)

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/a484c1d7834f195ac0cfccda6a9f905218bc2274/packages/stack/src/views/Header/HeaderTitle.tsx

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  title: Platform.select({
    ios: {
      fontSize: 17,
      fontWeight: '600',
    },
    android: {
      fontSize: 20,
      fontFamily: 'sans-serif-medium',
      fontWeight: 'normal',
    },
    default: {
      fontSize: 18,
      fontWeight: '500',
    },
  }),
});
```